# Dynamically adjusting the table height using DataTables

Tags: datatables

How do I adjust the table vertical scroll using DataTables? How to set the `scrollY` value dynamically?

I am using something like this: `scrollY : "300px"`. But I don't want to hard code the value. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using jQuery, replace `example` with your table ID.

```
$('#example').dataTable().fnSettings().oScroll.sY = '300px';
$('.dataTables_scrollBody:has(#example)').height('300px');
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L17dfrrg/2/) for demonstration.

Comment: Thanks fot the reply. But that dint't work. i want to display the scroll if only the records in my table are more. and i want to calculate the height and resize the scroll on page load itself.. hw do i do that ?

Comment: And am getting the scroll for the page which i dont want. I want the scroll only for the table if the record are more. Pls suggest

Comment: I have added the [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/L17dfrrg/2/) that shows that the code works.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Scroll bar doesn't appear if there are less rows than the table can display in one view.

Comment: That worked well.. But if i use the same snippet in large or small screens, its not fitting to the page since am defining the scrollY as 350px.. is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: If you want to fit table into the screen, you would need to adjust its size on page load and window resize events. Alternative option is to avoid using `scrollY` option and use [responsive plug-in](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) instead.

Comment: If i dont use the scrollY, am getting the page scroll bars also.. I need the scrolls only for the table and the header of the table shud b fixed for scrolling . can u help me on that ?? completely new to this track